# Android Extract String from Okhttp onResponse Function

Tags: java, android, string, handler, okhttp

I would like to get String value from onResponse function in OkHttp3 using Android Studio, which is

> final String title_name = jsonarray_news_extract_Data(jsonStr, index)

in below codes.
I've tried insert String variable "a" in argument, but it said

> Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final

so that I declared as final then it said

> Cannot Assign a Value to Final Variable

I tried to put

```
a = title_name;
```

after removed Handler method but still not work.

If you have any idea please help me out.
Thank you

```
public void news_From_API_Title(String url_news, final int index, final TextView textView, String a){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url_news)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {}

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
            final String jsonStr = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
            final String title_name = jsonarray_news_extract_Data(jsonStr, index);

            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    a = title_name;
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

private String jsonarray_news_extract_Data(String jsonString_News, int index){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString_News);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");
        return jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getString("title");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: you can use a string array whose size is one and using that u can store the value whenever you come across such a situation better approach would be to use a data model and have setters for the model. array approach -> final String[ ] a = new String[1] and then a[0] = title_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom `interface` like this:

```
interface ApiCallback{
    void onOkHttpResponse(String data);
    void onOkHttpFailure(Exception exception);
}
```

Then you pass not a `String` but an instance of `ApiCallback` into the method which is actually doing the call:

```
public void news_From_API_Title(String url_news, final int index, final TextView textView, ApiCallback callback){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url_news)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            callback.onOkHttpFailure(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
            final String jsonStr = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
            final String title_name = jsonarray_news_extract_Data(jsonStr, index);

            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callback.onOkHttpResponse(title_name);
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Now you can use an implementation of `ApiCallback` as follows:

```
String url_news = "https://some.web.address/news";
int index = 7;
TextView textView;
news_From_API_Title(url_news, index, textView, new apiCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onOkHttpResponse(String data){
        // do something with data here
        Log.d("TEST", "data = " + data);
    }

    @Override
    onOkHttpFailure(Exception exception){
        // exception handling
    }
});
```

---

Please note that it may be better from an architecture point of view if you don't pass the `TextView` as parameter into the method but instead set the text in `onOkHttpResponse()`:

```
// TextView will be initialized before calling news_From_API_Title()
// either make TextView a field (then use "private") 
// or declare it locally (then use "final")
private TextView textView;

// ... other code ...

String url_news = "https://some.web.address/news";
int index = 7;

// method will only take parameters which are not related to the UI 
// since it's desirable to avoid tight coupling of networking and UI components 
news_From_API_Title(url_news, index, new apiCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onOkHttpResponse(String data){
        // do something with data here
        // e.g. show data in TextView
        textView.setText(data);
    }

    @Override
    onOkHttpFailure(Exception exception){
        // exception handling
    }
});
```

Comment: I am so appreciate your answer. I'd like to pass the String value into another fragment and using interface works perfectly. And also thank you for advising about the Textview. I'd forgotten to delete before I posted. Anyway your answer works great! Thank you very much!